# How can I count occurrences of unique items per column across columns in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Say I have a `dataframe` that looks as follows:

| Index | one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | B | C |
| Second | C | A | B |
| Third | B | A | C |

My desired out is the counts of `df.iloc[:,1:]:` across the columns.

| Item | one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 2 |

Explanation for the second table counts in parenthesis next to each count.

| Item | one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 (Only one A in column 1) | 2 (two counts of A in column 2) | 0 (No A in column 3) |
| B | 1(Only one B in column 1) | 1 (Only one B in column 2) | 1 (1 B in column 3) |
| C | 1 (Only one C in column 1) | 0 (No Cs in column 2) | 2 (two counts of C in column 3) |

I have tried the following that did not quite work:

- `df3.iloc[:,1:].value_counts().to_frame('counts').reset_index()`
- `df[df.columns[1:]].value_counts()`

The above two one-liners are close but not quite there.

A Macgyvered solution I can think of is to loop through the columns one by one and do `.value_counts()` on each of them and try to organize the counts but that gets a bit messy given the order of each `.value_count` is somewhat different.

How should I do this?

Comment: why is first column two for B the value 2?  I don't see the pattern

Comment: Because there is 2 counts of A in column two, 1 count for B (in column two) and 0 count for C (in column two).  Count items per column across columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
```

Hoope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure? I am getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure, as i copy pasted your exact DataFrame and got the exact output you are seeking. probably the actual data in your DataFrame isn't as simple as in your question, do you have a list as a value or sth, somewhere in the Dataframe?

Comment: You were right, I had a couple of lists in there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """Index    one two three
First   A   B   C
Second  C   A   B
Third   B   A   C"""

df  = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\t').set_index('Index')

df = (df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
      .apply(pd.to_numeric,downcast='integer')
      .reset_index()
      .rename(columns={'index':'Item'})
     )
```

###### `>>> display(df)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use value_counts in an apply for the dataframe

```
data="""Index,one,two,three
First,A,B,C
Second,C,A,B
Third,B,A,C
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',')


df=df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).fillna(0)
df=df.drop(labels=['First','Second','Third'],axis=0)

print(df)
```